# Maven library don’t get dependency from private repository inside POM

Tags: android, maven, gradle, repository, nexus

I've been banging my head on this problem for a few days.

My situation is this:

- I have a sdk written by me that uses two dependencies hosted on a private maven repository which can only be accessed via login

  - **repo-1** hosted on S3 maven
  - **repo-2** hosted on Nexus
- This sdk was always used within my Android app (but treated as a sub-module) within the project.
- Inside the project’s Gradle there are the 2 maven repositories from which to look for the 2 private dependencies mentioned above.

```xml
maven {
    name “repo-1”
    url "s3://repo-1/maven"
    credentials(AwsCredentials) {
        accessKey awsUsername
        secretKey awsPassword
    }
}

maven {
    name “repo-2”
    url "http://repo-2/repository/maven-releases"
    credentials {
        username ‘repo-2-name’
        password ‘repo-2-password’
    }
}
```

- The 2 dependency mentioned above is used ONLY by the sdk, the app is completely unaware of it

Now I want to completely divide the two things and host the SDK on my private maven repository, in order to hide all the code and the dependencies concerning the SDK from the app.

First I want to do everything locally, so I could be faster to do different tests.
I therefore "uploaded" my SDK in my local maven.

In the POM that I generated, I have all the necessary dependencies to the SDK (including the 2 dependencies of the private repositories)like this :

```
<packaging>aar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                 <artifactId>repo-1</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.repo-1.android</groupId>
                    <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <artifactId>repo-2</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.repo-2.android</groupId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in addition i have also added the 2 repositories from which the 2 private dependencies must be downloaded :

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo-1</id>
            <name>repository-1</name>
            <url>http://repo-1/repository/maven-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo-2</id>
            <name>repository-2</name>
            <url>s3://repo-1/maven</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

I then set the **settings.xml** file , in the root of my local maven (../.m2) , with the credentials to access the 2 repositories.

```
<settings 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
        https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
     <servers>
            <server>
                <id>repo-1</id>
                <username>awsPassword</username>
                <password>awsPassword</password>
            </server>
            <server>
                <id>repo-2</id>
                <username>repo-2-name</username>
                <password>repo-2-password</password>
            </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

I then added my sdk as a dependency within the app, but does not want to download the 2 dependencies from the private repositories.

BUT

If I add the two maven repository in the gradle of the app project (like the first example), however, it works, so I'm pretty sure it's a problem of **pom** and **setting.xml** configuration.

Thank you very much to everyone for any answers

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

What you are facing is a difference between the way Maven and Gradle handle repositories.

In short Gradle is more strict and *will not transparently download* dependencies from repositories that are not declared in a build script.

For more details on why this is the case, have a look at [the discussion in the Gradle issue tracker](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8811).

So the solution, as you found out, is to declare these repositories in the consuming build script.
If you believe that's too verbose, consider writing a minimal plugin for your SDK that would add the dependencies and the repositories.

It would then become:

```
plugins {
    id 'my-sdk-plugin'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know some example plugin for doing this ? The result I would like to obtain is a plugin that deals only with importing the 2 repositories, nothing else. Do you think it is possible to insert credentials inside too, so that I don't need to insert anything inside the app, apart from applying the plugin ?

Comment: I am also working on this same problem, did you find any solution? @AndreaRubeis